# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[,]' to type 'System.Object[]'

Tags: c#, .net, object

I have a dll which gives me as an output an Object[,]

```
 {Name = "Object[,]" FullName = "System.Object[,]"}
```

I am trying to convert it to Object[] to be able to read it properly, as it is a two columns object. 
I have tried to cast it `Object[] values = (Object[])data;`, but I obtained the error from the tittle:

```
   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[,]' to type 'System.Object[]'.
```

Is there any easy way to perform this operation? I would like to make a dictionary out of it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should first describe (pretty much for yourself) what kind of operation it is, before asking for an easy to perform it. It doesn't seem obvious how to make a single-dimensional array from a two-dimensional one.

Comment: Sorry, I said what I wanted to do at the very end. I want to create a dictionary out of my output

Comment: You cannot simply make a dictionary from array, because 1) array element (of type `object`) can be null while dictionary key cannot, and 2) array can contain duplicates, while dictionary keys should be unique. You should write your own logic for such a conversion, there's no any easy built-in way to solve everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using it as an `Object[]` (which it isn't), use the [`System.Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) API:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // For example
Array array = (Array) data;
for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    string key = (string) array.GetValue(i, 0);
    string value = (string) array.GetValue(i, 1);
    dictionary[key] = value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked out. Why is an Array and not an Object[], although it says the opposite?

Comment: @arodrisa: Not sure what you mean - but fundamentally, a 2-dimensional rectangular array is *not* a 1-dimensional array. If you had an `object[][]`, you could treat *that* as an `object[]`, but that's different to a `object[,]`.

Comment: what kind of variable is a object[,]?

Comment: @arodrisa: It's a rectangular array. I suggest at this point you look on MSDN for array details in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can only cast an instance of any type to another one if it implements both types. However `object[,]` does not derive from `object[]` so you can´t cast it to that type. At least you should provide which dimension (/column) of the array you want to handle further.

However it is unlcear why you need this. If you´re only interested on the colums instead of the rows then you might simply call `myArr[i, 0]` or whatever column you´re interested in within a loop on the first dimension of the array.

If you want to iterate your multidimensional array you may either flatten it:

```
foreach(var on in myArray) 
    Console.WriteLine(o);
```

Which will simply loop **all the elements** without considering its position in the array or

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.GetLength(myColumnIndex); i++) 
    Console.WriteLine(myArray[i, myColumnIndex]);
```

Whereby you get only those **elements within the given column**.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I wanted to create a dictionary out of it

Answer (score 0):

Well of course you cannot cast a multidimensional array to an single dimension array. It is illegal. Check [Casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

But as a solution to your problem could be the following logic

```
object[,] multiDimensionalArray = new object[,]
    {
        {1,2}, //first pair
        {3,4}, //second pair
        {5,6}  //third pair
    };

    Dictionary<object, object> dict = new Dictionary<object, object>();
                //total number of elements     //number of dimensions
    int pairs = multiDimensionalArray.Length / multiDimensionalArray.Rank; 

               //or you can use i < multiDimensionalArray.GetLength(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < pairs; i++)
    {
        dict.Add(multiDimensionalArray[i, 0], multiDimensionalArray[i, 1]);
    }
```